# Typescript extending generic component type doesn't satisfy the constraint

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a generic component with a generic type, which extends required `id` property `GenericComponent = <T extends { id: number }>`. Also I have the interface where `id` is not required:

```
interface DataInterface {
    id?: number;
}
```

In the `<App />` component I render it, checking for existing `id`, but TS expectedly throws the error:

```
Type 'DataInterface' does not satisfy the constraint '{ id: number; }'.
  Property 'id' is optional in type 'DataInterface' but required in type '{ id: number; }'
```

I see one way to avoid this: to create a new interface based on my interface and set `id` as required, like this:

```
interface DataWithIdInterface extends DataInterface {
    id: number
}
```

But maybe is there any better way?

The example:

```
interface DataInterface {
    id?: number;
}

type Props<T> = {
    data: T;
};

const GenericComponent = <T extends { id: number }>({ data }: Props<T>) => (
    <div>{data.id}</div>
);

const App = () => {
    const data = {
        id: undefined
    };

    if (data.id) {
        // error here
        return <GenericComponent<DataInterface> data={data} />;
    }

    return null;
};
```

[Playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-playground-forked-hllk4?file=/src/index.tsx)

Comment: Why not `T extends { id?: number }>` instead of `T extends { id: number }` if it's okay for `id` to be optional?

Comment: Just remove explicit generic argument and it will work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's an option, but you could use [`Required<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype). With it you can "convert" all optional properties of the given type to required. Maybe something like this?

```
return <GenericComponent<Required<DataInterface>> data={data} />;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do what you want.

`GenericComponent` *requires* a type that is a subtype of `{ id: number }`. `{ id?: number }` (or `{ id: number | undefined }`) is not compatible with that. In short, `GenericComponent` assumes that `id` is always going to be a `number` - you can't provide it with `undefined` or no value.

`{ id?: number }` is a *super*type of `{ id: number }`, much like how in classic OOP examples an Animal is a supertype of Cat, and you cannot provide an Animal to an interface that specifically requires a Cat.

The only way to do this is with some kind of wrapper, either like you've written in your example or perhaps by writing a higher-order component. Alternatively, just stick with an if statement - no need to write complicated code when simple code does the job.